# How to change a DIV or BODY with Javascript from a navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, menu

a quick question... How do I change the body (in a DIV) of a webpage from a navigation link?

I have music playing in the background and need it to keep playing through the navigation menu. I'm not sure how to code it but I think a function may be the way to go?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah man, that sounds like it'll be a lot of load on the server. If you def need to do it this way, you can use jQuery's .load();

Comment: This kind of tasks is usually performed with the used of frames. One hidden frame contains the player, which keeps on playing while the user surfs the site on the other frame that fills the viewport.

Comment: Is there an easier way to keep music playing through multiple pages?

Comment: @user3254098 Sure there is. You can store a variable on `sessionStorage` to "tell" the other pages that a player is already set up and working, so you won't have multiple players running.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
document.getElementById("idOfYourDiv").innerHtml = "<div>foo</div>";
```

to edit the body of `<div id='idOfYourDiv'></div>` in pure JavaScript.
The event you want to probably trigger is `onClick`.

If you want to use jQuery then you can use

```
$('#navigButton').click(function(){
    $('#idOfYourDiv').html("<div>foo</div>");    
});
```

Edit: Good point by Andy Holmes - take a look at jQuery's `load()` function in the API.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the amazing answers... I'll continue to work on it!